# How to export top-level headings of org-mode buffer to separate files?

Tags: org-mode, elisp, org-export

How can each top-level heading of an `org-mode` buffer be exported to a separate file named after the value of the corresponding `CUSTOM_ID` + (sanitized) title?

Let's say a buffer contains:

```
* Title of Heading 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: fibrillogenesis
  :END:
  Suspendisse potenti. Mauris ac felis vel velit tristique imperdiet.  

** Sub-Heading
   Nullam rutrum.

* Another Title for Heading 2
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: mitochondrion
  :END:
  Mauris mollis tincidunt felis.  Sed bibendum.
```

The final result would be a directory containing two files, one for each of the two top-level headings, with the format chosen at export time (HTML, LaTeX, etc.), with the following file names and content:

1. Filename of first exported heading: `fibrillogenesis-title-of-heading-1.[ext]`

   Exported content, corresponding to the original first top-level heading:

   ```
   * Title of Heading 1
     :PROPERTIES:
     :CUSTOM_ID: fibrillogenesis
     :END:
     Suspendisse potenti. Mauris ac felis vel velit tristique imperdiet.  

   ** Sub-Heading 
      Nullam rutrum.
   ```
2. Filename of second exported heading: `mitochondrion-another-title-for-heading-2.[ext]`

   Exported content, corresponding to the original second top-level heading:

   ```
   * Another Title for Heading 2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :CUSTOM_ID: mitochondrion
   :END:
   Mauris mollis tincidunt felis.  Sed bibendum.
   ```

I would be very grateful for any hint, direction, pseudocode, or (better) real code.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following command lets you choose a back-end and then exports each top-level subtree to a separate file:

```el
(defun org-export-all (backend)
  "Export all subtrees that are *not* tagged with :noexport: to
separate files.

Note that subtrees must have the :EXPORT_FILE_NAME: property set
to a unique value for this to work properly."
  (interactive "sEnter backend: ")
  (let ((fn (cond ((equal backend "html") 'org-html-export-to-html)
                  ((equal backend "latex") 'org-latex-export-to-latex)
                  ((equal backend "pdf") 'org-latex-export-to-pdf))))
    (save-excursion
      (set-mark (point-min))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (org-map-entries (lambda () (funcall fn nil t)) "-noexport" 'region-start-level))))
```

This currently supports HTML (`html`), LaTeX (`latex`), and PDF (`pdf`) export.
You can add support for more back-ends by adding more clauses to `cond`.

As the docstring says, for each subtree you need to set the `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` property to the file name you want it to be exported to. (See below for other options.)

#### Automatically generating export file name from heading text

If you don't want to add `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` properties to every top-level heading, you can modify `org-export-all` to generate the filename automatically from e.g. the heading text, temporarily setting `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` during export:

```el
(defun org-export-all (backend)
  "Export all subtrees that are *not* tagged with :noexport: to
separate files.

Subtrees that do not have the :EXPORT_FILE_NAME: property set
are exported to a filename derived from the headline text."
  (interactive "sEnter backend: ")
  (let ((fn (cond ((equal backend "html") 'org-html-export-to-html)
                  ((equal backend "latex") 'org-latex-export-to-latex)
                  ((equal backend "pdf") 'org-latex-export-to-pdf)))
        (modifiedp (buffer-modified-p)))
    (save-excursion
      (set-mark (point-min))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (org-map-entries
       (lambda ()
         (let ((export-file (org-entry-get (point) "EXPORT_FILE_NAME")))
           (unless export-file
             (org-set-property
              "EXPORT_FILE_NAME"
              (replace-regexp-in-string " " "_" (nth 4 (org-heading-components)))))
           (funcall fn nil t)
           (unless export-file (org-delete-property "EXPORT_FILE_NAME"))
           (set-buffer-modified-p modifiedp)))
       "-noexport" 'region-start-level))))
```

This function generates the export filename by replacing spaces with "_" in the headline text. If you want to generate the filename some other way, change the `replace-regexp-in-string` sexp to whatever you like.

#### Generating `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` when setting `:CUSTOM_ID:`

With the following advice, `org-set-property` will automatically set an appropriate value for `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` when you set `:CUSTOM_ID:`:

```el
(defadvice org-set-property (after set-export-file-name
                                   (property value) activate compile)
  (when (equal org-last-set-property "CUSTOM_ID")
    (let ((export-file-name
           (concat (org-entry-get nil "CUSTOM_ID")
                   "-"
                   (replace-regexp-in-string " " "-" (downcase (org-get-heading t t))))))
      (org-entry-put nil "EXPORT_FILE_NAME" export-file-name))))
```

Note that this will not add a file extension to the value of `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` but that doesn't matter because when exporting to a specific back-end, `org-mode` *will automatically choose the correct extension for the resulting files*.

---

### Additional information

#### Updating existing subtrees in bulk

If you have a large number of existing subtrees that you need to set the `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` property for, you can use a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html). Position point on the first subtree, then do the following:

- <kbd>F3</kbd>

  ... to start recording.
- <kbd>C-c C-x p</kbd> `CUSTOM_ID` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

  ... to make Emacs set `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` based on `:CUSTOM_ID:`.
- <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>

  ... to move to the next top-level headline.
- <kbd>F4</kbd>

  ... to stop recording.

To repeat the macro for the next subtree, press <kbd>F4</kbd>. To repeat the macro for *all* remaining subtrees, press <kbd>M-0</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> (that's a zero).

#### Saving macros for future sessions

By default, keyboard macros are not saved across sessions. To store the macro in your init-file for later use, do this:

1. Name the macro:

   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `name-last-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-set-export-file-name` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Find your init-file and move to a spot where you would like to insert the macro.
3. Insert the macro:

   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-set-export-file-name` <kbd>RET</kbd>

   Emacs will insert the following code at point:

   ```el
   (fset 'org-set-export-file-name
      "\C-c\C-xpCUSTOM_ID\C-m\C-m\C-c\C-f")
   ```

   If you squint hard enough you can see that the second argument to `fset` contains the sequence of keys that you pressed when you recorded the macro :)
4. (Optional) For best results, you might want to bind `org-set-export-file-name` to a key:

   ```el
   (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") 'org-set-export-file-name)
   ```
5. Save.

Comment: Nice. Could you give me a hint on how to programmatically set `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` property to `:CUSTOM_ID:+heading-title-lowercased` for each heading?

Comment: @gsl You could advise `org-set-property` to automatically generate the `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` property when you set `:CUSTOM_ID:`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I am not that fluent with `elisp`, but I shall try. I need to find out how to capture each heading's title, substitute white space with dash, put to lowercase, add that sanitised string to `:CUSTOM_ID:` and finally set an org property.

Comment: @gsl I added a `defadvice` to my answer that automatically sets `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` to `<custom-id>-<heading>` when you set `:CUSTOM_ID:`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have learned a lot with your code. If one would have already an `org-mode` file with `CUSTOM_ID`s set, how one could run the code to set "EXPORT_FILE_NAME"? There wouldn't be new insertions. I am guessing `defadvice` would not work? Is there a looping facility to traverse all top-level headings and apply the code to them?

Comment: @gsl You can use a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) to achieve that. I'll add some info about that to my answer.

Comment: @gsl You're welcome :) PS: Note that I changed `C-c C-n` to `C-c C-f` in the macro definition. This helps make sure you are only touching top-level subtrees.

Comment: Is it possible to instead "temporarily" set `:EXPORT_FILE_NAME:` in the `org-export-all` function, so that you don't need to modify the file?

Comment: I think this code had a bug. `org-map-entries` by default maps over *all* headings in the buffer, not just the top-level ones. Annoyingly, the only way to restrict `org-map-entries` to top-level headings is with the `region-start-level` option, which means you have to set the active region to the whole buffer before calling it. I've modified the code to fix this.

Comment: @avv This is Emacs - of course it's possible! :) I've added a variant of `org-export-all` to the answer that temporarily sets `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` to a filename derived from the headline text, if it wasn't already set.

Comment: This is a really great answer.  I think the current solutin fails if there is any text before the first headline in the buffer(e.g., org settings lines).  I've modified the save-excursion part (can't post whole fn in comment)

    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (set-mark (re-search-forward "
*"))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (org-map-entries (lambda () (funcall fn nil t)) "-noexport" 'region-start-level))