# Publishing top-level orgmode entiries in separate files automatically

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

In org-mode, how can I "publish" all of the top level headings in separate files. Publishing involves moving files while making the required transformation. The transformation is from org to html. There is a similar question talking about exporting

[How to export top-level headings of org-mode buffer to separate files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/how-to-export-top-level-headings-of-org-mode-buffer-to-separate-files)

That solution is great and it works for exporting to html, pdf, and latex. Differently, I would like to avoid the interactive part and use the above functionality as a "publish" function in emacs. I may be still interested in different formats, however, since publishing is a batch function, it would not make sense to stop and ask for user input.

What can be done? Any  help would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance